# No errors but code doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin, backend

I created a contact form and I can't seem to find the error in the code now my problem is this when I click the Submit button it returns a blank page without displaying any error.

[This is the result I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnGeT.jpg)

[Link to the script contact.html(php actually)](https://script.google.com/d/1Ofq80FF6Nl51svb1V6vVyeujV4jyilDH2TyCzh6jLFKV0s1Jd18xG2NK/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Add this to your php page, and you will probably see errors :ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: It's  a live script so I disabled error reporting but there's no error either on my error_log file

Comment: Have you checked front-end errors maybe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error reporting is probably not set to display errors, it doesn't mean that there is none.

Add the followings line to your php page :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You'll then see errors.

If you don't want errors to display and it's an ajax request to your php script, you can console.log the server response into your javascript request handler :)

Comment: @ChukwukaMavin Thanks for the link, testing it right now.

Comment: The problem is I don't want the errors to be visible to my users, Is there any other way I can get past this

Comment: @ChukwukaMavin cannot find the dns.. (I'm in South Korea, probably the time for the dns to spread)

Comment: @ChukwukaMavin Is there any specific error log file that is assigned to this website in your server configuration (vhost for apache for example ) ?

Comment: Yes there is but it;s blank @sorikairo

Comment: @ChukwukaMavin I see a POST https://appexfund.com/member/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

Try to console.log the server response into your javascript handler, it will display what has gone wrong

Comment: Ok i'd do that @sorikairo